# Change axis of Fork Extrude

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I'm not finding it anywhere. I want to create symmetrical shoulder bones for my armature. So I want to use a fork extrude. As you can see in the image below the fork is on the wrong axis. I know I cannot change the orientation of the axis so I tried changing the orientation of the mesh and armature but no luck there. I have x-axis mirror in tools and axes in armature setting selected. Does anyone know how to re-orientate how these are extruding?[image]

Comment: FILE LINK: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1486" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1486/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rigging is admittedly not my expertise, but if I understand correctly, this has to do with unapplied transforms, and the direction the model is facing. You have *x axis mirror* enabled, but are parallel to the x axis (model facing left ortho view) so are unable to properly mirror to get the expected results.

I would first rotate your model 90 degrees on the Z axis to face *front ortho* view, and *apply transforms* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and you should be able to proceed as desired. See .gif below for the steps:

[image]

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help.